# WordPress files not seeing /~username/ on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a localhost running on **localhost/~frederoover/**, everything works perfect, but when I install a WordPress website, I'm getting the following issue's.

**localhost/~frederoover/agri-travel.be** loads just fine, but the internal files all give a 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' and they are pointing to **localhost/wp-content/plugins/***. So WordPress doesn't see my /~username/.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: You clearly have something very wrong with your file structure - add your file structure to your question

Comment: The file structure from my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf?

Comment: Yeah, what's your overall file structure as none of your included files are being found - what server are you using? Is it definitely running?

Answer (score 0):

Your [site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) is incorrect. The easiest way to fix this to add this to your `wp-config.php` and load the home page:

```php
define('RELOCATE', true);
```

Make sure to remove it after you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Export your database as `.sql` open the file using text editor. find the `http://localhost` and replace with `http://localhost/~frederoover/sgri-travel.be` and again import it. This will work.!

**Step 2:** Update `siteurl` and `home`

Next you need to change the location of your site in the database.

In wp_options, locate siteurl and home. Usually these records are at the top of the table on line 1 and 2.
For siteurl, click the field under option_value and replace the old domain with your new domain name ( `http://localhost/~frederoover/sgri-travel.be` in your case ).
Press enter to save.
Do the same for home.
[image]

**Step 3:** Fix permalinks **(Optional)**

If you experience that you get a 404 error when you try to open links on your site, the Permalinks are broken. Luckily it is very easy to fix this.

Log in to your WordPress dashboard.
Click Settings and then Permalinks
Scroll down and click Save Changes.
[image]